# What does it mean when you add 'おっか' to the stem of a verb?

Tags: grammar, meaning, verbs

I've been reading, playing, and watching a lot of Japanese content recently and I keep running into this construction. I feel like I get the gist of it's meaning but I don't know exactly what it means. Here are a few examples of what I've come across: 始めおっか, 手伝おっか, and 何か飲もっか.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a rendering of a colloquial pronunciation of volitional (-よう) + か. So, 何か飲もっか (＝何か飲もうか), that is, "Shall we have something to drink?".

The first example should be 始めよっか, by the way.